# UIWebView WTFCrash CSSParser::addNamespace

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, webkit

We are facing the following crash in our iOS Cordova based app:

```
Crashed: WebThread
0  JavaScriptCore                 0x187a3b22c WTFCrash + 72
1  JavaScriptCore                 0x187a3b224 WTFCrash + 64
2  WebCore                        0x187d6c4fc WebCore::CSSParser::addNamespace(WTF::AtomicString const&, WTF::AtomicString const&) + 186
3  WebCore                        0x188a6ecac WebCore::TextResourceDecoder::decodeAndFlush(char const*, unsigned long) + 192
4  WebCore                        0x187cb5c9c WebCore::CachedScript::script() + 72
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x187a21f20 std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::FunctionNode, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::FunctionNode> > JSC::parse<JSC::FunctionNode>(JSC::VM*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::FunctionParameters*, JSC::Identifier const&, JSC::JSParserBuiltinMode, JSC::JSParserStrictMode, JSC::JSParserCodeType, JSC::ParserError&, JSC::JSTextPosition*, JSC::ConstructorKind, JSC::ThisTDZMode) + 88
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x187a21550 JSC::UnlinkedFunctionExecutable::codeBlockFor(JSC::VM&, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::DebuggerMode, JSC::ProfilerMode, JSC::ParserError&) + 156
7  JavaScriptCore                 0x1877a3440 JSC::ScriptExecutable::newCodeBlockFor(JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSFunction*, JSC::JSScope*, JSC::JSObject*&) + 508
8  JavaScriptCore                 0x1877a3a70 JSC::ScriptExecutable::prepareForExecutionImpl(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSFunction*, JSC::JSScope*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind) + 104
9  JavaScriptCore                 0x1875229b0 JSC::LLInt::setUpCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Instruction*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSValue, JSC::LLIntCallLinkInfo*) + 164
10 JavaScriptCore                 0x187961e58 llint_entry + 23912
11 JavaScriptCore                 0x187961d44 llint_entry + 23636
```

I have tried to check the source code and found the following:

```
void CSSParser::addNamespace(const AtomicString& prefix, const AtomicString& uri)
{
    if (!m_styleSheet || !m_allowNamespaceDeclarations)
        return;
    m_allowImportRules = false;
    m_styleSheet->parserAddNamespace(prefix, uri);
    if (prefix.isEmpty() && !uri.isNull())
        m_defaultNamespace = uri;
}
```

But I can't just figure out where could the WTFCrash be happening. Any idea?